# Javascript/AJAX works on home but not secondary pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Using Wordpress on 4 sites I just created for a client.  I have a sidebar with a script that uses Google Maps API and estimates taxi fare.  The script is working fine on the home page, but doesn't work on any of the secondary pages.  What would be causing this behavior?  One of the sites is http://yellowcaboffolsom.net.  Try the calculator on the home page, then try it on any of the other pages.
I'm stumped on this one.
Jake B

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual code in question here so we dont have to go searching for it.

Comment: You have a gmaps api key for all domains and set up correctly?

Comment: The API key has the domains setup like this:
sacramentoairporttaxi.net/*
sacramentotaxi.us/*
yellowcaboffolsom.net/*
longdistancetaxicab.com/*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your entire problem, but on that site, the function book2() is assigning a value to a variable named pickUp, but the variable you initialized is named pickUP (with a capitalized "P". I'd say first step is making the variable names match, and then you can see if the other issue still reproduces.

Comment: I don't think that value is used at all.  I fixed it but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the console, hit the button, and it tells you the issues.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pickUp is not defined /make-taxi-reservations/?destinationF=1689+Arden+Way%2C+Sacramento%2C+CA&destinationF=1600+Exposition+Boulevard%2C+Sacramento%2C+CA&address1=1689+Arden+Way%2C+Sacramento%2C+CA&address2=1600+Exposition+Boulevard%2C+Sacramento%2C+CA#:220
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined myScript.js:9
```